# Django REST Framework @detail_route not working as expected

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I can't get @detail_route to work as I think it is supposed to.

I have two API calls I want to handle:

```js
/movie/
/movie/highlight
```

I am trying to use @detail_route to pickup the /movie/highlight url in the viewset.

My urls.py looks like this:

```js
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from api import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UsersViewSet) 
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet) 
router.register(r'movie', views.MovieViewSet)
```

My views.py looks like this:

```js
rom django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from movies.models import Movie

from api.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer, MovieSerializer

from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework import renderers
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route

# Code from DRF quickstart tutorial
class UsersViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

# Code from DRF quickstart tutorial
class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer

# MY CODE
class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Movie.objects.all().order_by('-title')
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

    @detail_route(renderer_classes=(renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer,))
    def highlight(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        snippet = "Highlight"
        return Response(snippet)
```

The serializers.py looks like this:

```js
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from movies.models import *
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')


class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('url', 'name')

# My code...
class MovieSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('title', 'details')
```

If I try the /movie/ url API call it works as expected. If I try the /movie/highlight/ call I get a 404 error.

I am a newbie to DRF so suspect I am doing something very silly here but can't find out what from the various docs and tutorials I have scanned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You need to use `@list_route` decorator instead of `@detail_route` decorator.**

This will generate the url `movie/highlight/`.

Using `@list_route` decorated method generates the url of type `{prefix}/{methodname}/` whereas `detail_route` decorated method generateds url of type `{prefix}/{lookup}/{methodname}/`. Here `methodname` is name of your method and `lookup` is the lookup value on which lookup is performed to get the object for detail view.

```
class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Movie.objects.all().order_by('-title')
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

    # use list_route decorator
    @list_route(renderer_classes=(renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer,))
    def highlight(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        snippet = "Highlight"
        return Response(snippet)
```

Comment: Excellent! I could have sworn I had tried that but clearly not!

Comment: If I was to use @detail_route for a url of the form: movie/<id>/highlight/ how would I access the <id> in the highlight method?

Comment: @BillNoble You can access it using, self.kwargs['pk']

Comment: @BillNoble [Tevin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1407202/tevin-joseph-k-o) has correctly mentioned, you can use access the url arguments in your views using `kwargs`.

Answer (score 0):

If you register your URLs using **routers.DefaultRouter()**, it will generate the URL **/movie/pk/highlight** instead of **/movie/highlight**. If you want a custom URL other than the pre-generated one, use URL mapping.

Comment: I don't understand why you think I am getting /movie//highlight but trying that still doesn't work.

Comment: @BillNoble Updated the answer. Editor didn't display the *pk* in my answer.